# What can I substitute for "A perfect example for this is"

Tags: sentence-starts, single-word-requests

I need a more sophisticated way of starting a sentence that uses soccer as a perfect example of an ancestral sport from china which evolved.

Comment: A textbook illustration of this ... (though this sounds like a pun; 'textbook example' is perhaps better).

Comment: I suppose 'exemplar' might sound sophisticated, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: For a widely used perfect example, 'paradigm' is good.